# Cannot call function on Symfony2 websocket connection

Tags: symfony, websocket, phpwebsocket, ratchet

First off im using the JDare/ClankBundle 
I'm following these instruction to call a function from the client side
https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/RPCSetup.md

I keep gettting this error on the console "RPC Error [object Object] undefined"

I noticed that it doesn't matter if I mispell the notify_func function, it still throws the same error. 
I don't know what im doing wrong, but I assume the function isn't found to begin with?

> This is the client side (Twig)

The websocket connects succesfully

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var myClank = Clank.connect('ws://localhost:9999');

        myClank.on("socket/connect", function(session){
            alertify.success("Connected to websocket server");

            //this will call the server side function "Sample::addFunc"
            session.call("notify/notify_func",[2,5])
                .then(  //using "then" promises.

                    function(result) //the function for a valid result
                    {
                        alertify.log("RPC Valid! "+result);
                    },
                    function(error, desc) // the function to handle an error
                    {
                        alertify.log("RPC Error"+" "+error+" "+desc);
                    }

                );
        });

        myClank.on("socket/disconnect", function(error){
            alertify.error("Disconnect for "+error.reason+" with code "+error.code);
        });
    </script>
```

This is the server side

```
    <?php
namespace Gabriel\NotificationsBundle\RPC;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface as Conn;

class PostCommentNotificationService
{
    public function notifyFunc(Conn $conn,$params)
    {
        return array("result"=>array_sum($params));
    }
}
```

This is the config

```
#services.yml
services:
     notifications.newcommentpost:
       class: Gabriel\NotificationsBundle\RPC\PostCommentNotificationService
#config.yml
     # Clank Configuration
clank:
    web_socket_server:
        port: 9999       #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: localhost   #(optional) The host ip to bind to
    rpc:
       -
        name: "notify" #Important! this is the network namespace used to match calls to this service!
        service: "notifications.newcommentpost" #The service id.
```

Comment: Had you solved the problem? On which console are u getting error? on browser console or on from where u r running server? I had test your code in my system it is working fine for me. I had not use alertify js i had used console.log.

Comment: This is a very old question, I ended up uninstalling the clank bundle and implementing my own logic using native php websockets

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.

I found out that stopping and restarting the built-in websocket server solved the problem. Every modification done on the websocket code requires the  websocket server to be restarted in order for these changes to take place...

```
php app/console clank:server
```